# Amazon S3 Fetching Error: "NoSuchKey" However Key Does Exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch a S3 Object using AWS Storage

```js
fetchAvatar = async () => {
  try {
      const imageData = await Storage.get("public/public/us-east-2:/1597842961073/family.jpg")
      console.log(imageData)
  } catch (err) {
      console.log('error fetching avatar: ')
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

When I click on the link that the imageData provides I get NoSuchKey error, however it does exist
[image: Image of Key]

I've made sure that the image is public and accessible by everyone, so there shouldn't be any authentication problems. I've also looked at similar issue to this and I made sure there is no spaces or a lot of special keys in my image keys. I am kind of stumped on this...

Comment: Also If I get on the S3 Management Console, and click on the image, it does exist and is downloadable manually..idk if this helps, but i hope it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the reason, and it has to do something with AWS S3 Management. For some reason that every time I upload an image, the folder will reset and become privet. When I remake the folders and image public manually I am able to render the image properly...So i guess it is more of AWS issue or bug that they need to fix I think

Comment: It's a safe assumption that the problem is not inside S3 but that there is something about your setup that you do not understand.  There is no such thing as a folder resetting and becoming private, because there is no such thing as folder-level permissions in S3 except as handled in IAM policies, which you didn't mention and would not be modified by uploading objects.  Enable logging on your bucket and what is actually happening should become apparent from the logs.

Comment: Yeah so I am kind of new to AWS but I figured it out, I just had to add a new policy to the bucket due to it being automatically private. And it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [javascript aws sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html), you can get an object from the bucket like below:

```
 var params = {
    Bucket: "your-bucket-name", 
    Key: "yourFileName.jpg"
 };
 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);  
 });
```

UPDATE:

You can define your region when you create a s3 instance, like:

```
const s3 = new S3({
  region: 'eu-central-1',
});
```

Comment: will I need to add a region in the params as well? since s3 objects are made of key, bucket, and region?

Comment: @StevanNajeeb You can define your region when you create a s3 instance, I'll update the answer, something like: const sqs = new S3({
  region: 'eu-central-1',
});